# Unique identification of Firebase Analytics event record

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Firebase Analytics connected to BigQuery and the BQ table schema is described here:

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846

I would like to find out how each event record can be uniquely identified.

Originally I thought that a combination of a

**user_pseudo_id** and **event_timestamp**

is to be unique. But I found out that it is not unique...

I added: **event_date**, **event_name**, **event_previous_timestamp**, **stream_id**, etc. into the 'group by' clause, but nothing helps.

Can anybody advise me, what makes the event record unique, please?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? There is probably a way for you to do it without having a unique ID for each event.

Comment: Hi @Vesper - I am trying to understand a sequence of events - for funnel analysis. When I come across a few identical rows in the table - I am not - sure - which of them to be chosen, and why I've got 9 (or any other number) records instead of one.

Comment: Hi. It would help if you could clarify/give some example of your problem in the question. The query producing these identical rows would also help.

Comment: OK. Since Google changed the way how the BQ accepts the data from the Firebase Analytics (for me it means since 25/06/2018) there were 4 data night ingestions. As a result of that, I've got 18 281 681 events. From them, 178 309 distinct event records have duplications so the number of duplications comes to 364 224. Thus the number of redundant records is 364 224 - 178 309 = 185 915 or about 1 percent of the total number of records.

Comment: a query is too long to insert. I simply take all columns, group by them and count cases with the number of records in a group > 1

Comment: And this produces multiple rows with identical data? Same type of event, same user, same timestamp? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Lucky you. Thank you very much for the help attempt.

Comment: @al-dann: Could you provide some info regarding the event names that were returned when you used (user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp)? Were they duplicated events, or just a random collision.

Comment: About duplicated records

-- query:
#standardSQL
select 
  count(*) as numb_of_rec
  , count (distinct concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string))) as numb_of_distinct_rec
  , count(*) - count (distinct concat(user_pseudo_id, cast(event_timestamp as string))) as difference
from
  `ZZZZ.events_20180701`
 
-- results 
-- numb_of_rec     numb_of_distinct_rec  difference
--   7 830 899           7 797 264      33 635

Comment: A similar issue is indicated if I run a query like this one:

#standardSQL
select 
  user_pseudo_id     as user_pseudo_id
  , event_timestamp  as event_timestamp
  , count(*)         as number_of_rec
from
  `ZZZZ.events_20180701`
group by 
  user_pseudo_id
  , event_timestamp
having number_of_rec > 1

Comes back with 32 279 records. sum(count(*)) => 65 914 records

Comment: On top of the previous queries I can get a list of event names which a duplicated:

#standardSQL
with src as
(
select 
  user_pseudo_id     as user_pseudo_id
  , event_timestamp  as event_timestamp
  , count(*)         as number_of_rec
from
  `ZZZZ.analytics_YYYY.events_20180701`
group by 
  user_pseudo_id
  , event_timestamp
having number_of_rec > 1
)

Comment: , evt as
(
select 
  e.event_name         as event_name
  , e.user_pseudo_id   as user_pseudo_id
  , e.event_timestamp  as event_timestamp 
from
  `ZZZZ.analytics_YYYY.events_20180701` e
  inner join src on
  (e.event_timestamp = src.event_timestamp and e.user_pseudo_id = src.user_pseudo_id)
)
select 
  evt.event_name         as event_name
  , count(*)             as numb_of_rec
from 
  evt
group by 
  event_name
order by numb_of_rec desc;

Comment: Comes back with a few dozens of records… Among custom events there are some standard. For example:

‘user_engagement’ => 18 082
‘session_start’ => 1029
‘in_app_purchase’ => 97
‘app_update’ => 57

An so on… sum(numb_of_rec) => 65 914 - reconciled nicely...

Comment: Next. I used to check the documentation page https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846 every day. And every day there are some modifications. For example, today 2 new fields appear in the migration script and in the fields description: 

user_dim.bundle_info.bundle_sequence_id as event_bundle_sequence_id,
user_dim.bundle_info.server_timestamp_offset_micros as event_server_timestamp_offset,

Comment: So I think that tomorrow those fields may appear in the table (so starting from tomorrow the table schema is going to be modified again, and becomes incompatible with the previous days and scripts). That probably will resolve the issue, which I guess was caused by the absence of these information https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.analytics.ExportBundleInfo in the Firebase to BigQuery export. But this is only my guess...

Answer (score 0):

We are using Google Advertising ID as unique device ID. A user may have logged on to your app with multiple devices but using the same account, so in this case user_id is not unique, user_pseudo_id for the same device will change if he/she re-installs the app. Only assumption out here is that the user has not intentionally reset his/her GAID.The GAID field can be found under event_params with Key as gaid in BigQuery. Hope this helps!